# UseEffect is too slow and dont do my check in React

Tags: reactjs, return, use-effect

I have a problem with the following useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
      getOrder();
  }, []);
```

With `getOrder` i recover a row of my DB.

And then i have this:

```
if (order.tableId === tableID) {
    return (
      <>
      <h1>Text Example</h1>
      </>
    )
  } else {
     return (
      <>
      <h1>Text Example</h1>
      </>
     )
  }
```

The problem I have is that I get first that the variable `order.tableId` is `undefined` and then when the `if` has been done it returns the correct value. For example it returns the value of the order of a table, a 1.

All code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  CButton,
  CCol,
  CRow,
  CImage,
  CContainer,
  CTableRow,
  CTableHead,
  CTableBody,
  CTable,
  CTableHeaderCell,
  CTableDataCell,
  CModal,
  CModalHeader,
  CFormLabel,
  CModalTitle,
  CModalFooter,
  CModalBody,
  CForm,
  CFormInput,
  CInputGroup,
  CInputGroupText,
  CLink,
  CFormSelect,
  CNav,
  CNavGroup,
  CNavItem,
  CNavLink,
  CTabPane,
  CTabContent,
  CCardTitle,
  CCard,
  CCardBody,
  CCardText,
  CHeader,
  CHeaderBrand,
  CHeaderDivider,
  CHeaderNav,
  CHeaderToggler,
  CCardImage,
  CListGroup,
  CListGroupItem
} from '@coreui/react'
import { 
  FishIcon, 
  EggIcon,
  CeleryIcon,
  CrustaceanIcon,
  GlutenIcon,
  LupinIcon,
  MilkIcon,
  MolluscIcon,
  MustardIcon,
  NutsIcon,
  PeanutIcon,
  SesameIcon,
  SoyaIcon,
  SulphiteIcon,
 } from 'react-allergens';
import CIcon from '@coreui/icons-react'
import axios from "axios";
import { AppHeaderClient } from "./../../../components"
import { cilBell, cilEnvelopeOpen, cilList, cilMenu, cilExitToApp, cilCart, cilPlus, cibProductHunt, cilTrash } from '@coreui/icons'
import { getByPlaceholderText } from '@testing-library/react';
import { faBookOpenReader } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';


const Login = () => {

  const [productsList, setProductsList] = useState([]);
  const [sections, setSections] = useState([]);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
  const [activeKey, setActiveKey] = useState(1)
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
  const [order, setOrder] = useState([]);
  let totalPrice = 0;
  
  useEffect(() => {
      getOrder();
      getProducts();
      getSections();
  }, []);

  const getProducts = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('http://192.168.1.50:9000/getProducts', {
    });
    setProductsList(response.data);
    console.log(response.data)
  }
  const getSections = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('http://192.168.1.50:9000/getSections', {
    });
    setSections(response.data);
    console.log(response.data)
  }
  const getCart = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('http://192.168.1.50:9000/getCart?mesa='+tableID, {
    });
    setCart(response.data);
    console.log(response.data)
  }

  function handlerButtonCart() {
    setVisible(!visible);
    getCart();
  }

  const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const tableID = queryParams.get('mesa');

  const addProductToCart = async (e, productID) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("tableID: " + tableID + " productID: " + productID)
    try {
          await axios.post('http://192.168.1.50:9000/addProductToCart', {
            tableID: tableID,
            productID: productID,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            setMsg(error.response.data.msg);
        }
    }
  }

  const destroyProductCart = async (e, productID) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("tableID: " + tableID + " productID: " + productID)
    try {
          await axios.post('http://192.168.1.50:9000/destroyProductCart', {
            tableID: tableID,
            productID: productID,
        });
        window.location.reload();
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            setMsg(error.response.data.msg);
        }
    }
  }

  const addOrder = async (e, totalPrice, id) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("totalPrice: " + totalPrice + "mesa: " + id)
    try {
          await axios.post('http://192.168.1.50:9000/addOrder', {
            totalPrice: totalPrice,
            id: id,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            setMsg(error.response.data.msg);
        }
    }
  }

  const getOrder = async () => {
    const response = await axios.post('http://192.168.1.50:9000/getOrder', {
      tableID: tableID,
    });
    setOrder(response.data);
    console.log(response.data)
  }

  console.log(order.tableId)
  
  if (order.tableId === tableID) {
    return (
      <>
      <h1>Text Example</h1>
      </>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <CHeader position="sticky" className="mb-4">
        <CContainer fluid className="justify-content-center">
        
        <CNav className="justify-content-center">
          {sections.map((section,index) => {
          return (
          <CNavItem key={index}>
            <CNavLink className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" 
            href="javascript:void(0);"
            active={activeKey === 1}
            onClick={() => setActiveKey(section.id)}
            style={{color:"black"}}>
              {section.name}
            </CNavLink>
          </CNavItem>
          )})}
        </CNav>
        <CHeaderNav className="d-none d-md-flex me-auto">
          </CHeaderNav>
  
          <CHeaderToggler>
            <CIcon icon={cilCart} size="lg" onClick={handlerButtonCart}/>
          </CHeaderToggler>
        
        </CContainer>
      </CHeader>
        
        <CTabContent>
      
      {sections.map((section,index) => {
        return (
          <CTabPane key={section.id} role="tabpanel" visible={activeKey === section.id}>
            {productsList.filter(product => product.section == section.id).map((product,index) => {
                  var allergens = JSON.parse(product.allergens)
                  return (
                    <CContainer className='justify-content-center' key={product.id}>
                      <CCard className="justify-content-center mb-4">
                        <CRow className='g-0'>
                        <CCol md={4}>
                          <CCardImage align='center' className="clearfix" src={"http://192.168.1.50:9000/public/images/" + product.img} />
                        </CCol>
                        <CCol md={8}>
                              <CCardBody>
                                  <CContainer fluid>
                                    <CRow>
                                        <CRow>
                                        <h1>{product.name}</h1>
                                        <p>{product.description}</p>
                                        </CRow>
                                        <CRow className='mb-4'>
                                          {allergens.map(p => {
                                            switch (p.label) {
                                              case "Pescado":
                                                return <CCol xs={1}> <FishIcon width="25px" height="25px"/> </CCol>
                                                break;
                                              case "FrutosSecos":
                                                return <CCol xs={1}> <NutsIcon width="25px" height="25px"/> </CCol>
                                                break;
                                              case "Lacteos":
                                                return <CCol xs={1}> <MilkIcon width="25px" height="25px"/> </CCol>
                                                break;
                                              case "Moluscos":
                                                return <CCol xs={1}> <MolluscIcon width="25px" height="25px"/> </CCol>
                                                break;
                                              case "Cereales con gluten":
                                                return <CCol xs={1}> <GlutenIcon width="25px" height="25px"/> </CCol>
                                                break;
                                              case "Crustáceos":
                                                return <CCol xs={1}> <CrustaceanIcon width="25px" height="25px"/> </CCol>
                                                break;
                                              case "Huevos":
                                                return <CCol xs={1}> <EggIcon width="25px" height="25px"/> </CCol>
                                                break;
                                              case "Cacahuetes":
                                                return <CCol xs={1}> <PeanutIcon width="25px" height="25px"/> </CCol>
                                                break;
                                              case "Soja":
                                                return <CCol xs={1}> <SoyaIcon width="25px" height="25px"/> </CCol>
                                                break;
                                              case "Apio":
                                                return <CCol xs={1}> <CeleryIcon width="25px" height="25px"/> </CCol>
                                                break;
                                              case "Mostaza":
                                                return <CCol xs={1}> <MustardIcon width="25px" height="25px"/> </CCol>
                                                break;
                                              case "Sésamo":
                                                return <CCol xs={1}> <SesameIcon width="25px" height="25px"/> </CCol>
                                                break;
                                              case "Altramuces":
                                                return <CCol xs={1}> <LupinIcon width="25px" height="25px"/> </CCol>
                                                break;
                                              case "Sulfitos":
                                                return <CCol xs={1}> <SulphiteIcon width="25px" height="25px"/> </CCol>
                                                break;
                                              case "Ninguno":
                                                return <CCol xs={1}></CCol>
                                                break;
                                            }
                                          })
                                          }
                                          <CCol className="text-end">
                                            <h3>{product.price} €</h3>
                                          </CCol>
                                        </CRow>
                                       <CRow className="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
                                        <CCol xs={12} xl={3}>
                                          <CButton onClick={(e) => addProductToCart(e,product.id)} color="secondary">
                                          <CIcon icon={cilPlus}/> Añadir al carrito
                                          </CButton>
                                        </CCol>
                                        </CRow>
                                    </CRow>
                                  </CContainer>
                              </CCardBody>
                        </CCol>
                        
                        </CRow>
                      </CCard>
                    </CContainer>
                  )
              })}
          </CTabPane>
        )})}
      </CTabContent>
      <CModal size="xl" alignment="center" visible={visible} onClose={() => setVisible(false)}>
        <CModalHeader onClose={() => setVisible(false)}>
          <CModalTitle>Carrito</CModalTitle>
        </CModalHeader>
        <CModalBody>
          <CContainer className='justify-content-center'>
          {cart.map((product,index) => {
            totalPrice += (product["products.cart.qty"] * product["products.price"] );
            return(
                <CRow className='justify-content-center' key={index}>
                <CCol xs={9}>
                <CCard className="mb-3">
                   <CRow className="g-0">
                     <CCol md={4}>
                       <CCardImage src={"http://192.168.1.50:9000/public/images/" + product["products.img"]} />
                     </CCol>
                     <CCol md={8}>
                       <CCardBody>
                         <h3>{product["products.name"]}</h3>
                         <h4 className='text-end'>{product["products.price"]} €</h4>
                       </CCardBody>
                     </CCol>
                   </CRow>
                 </CCard>
                </CCol>
                <CCol xs={3} className="justify-items-content">
                   <CFormInput className='text-center' value={product["products.cart.qty"]}/>
                   <p></p>
                   <CButton className="float-end shadow-none" style={{color:"white", border:"none", boxShadow:"white", background:"white", boxShadowColor:"white"}} onClick={(e) => destroyProductCart(e,product["products.cart.productId"])}>
                    <CIcon style={{color:"red"}} icon={cilTrash} size="xl" />
                   </CButton>
                </CCol>
               </CRow>)
              })}
          </CContainer>
          <CModalFooter>
            <h3>{totalPrice} €</h3>
            <CButton color="success" onClick={(e) => addOrder(e,totalPrice,tableID)}>Pedir</CButton>
          </CModalFooter>
        </CModalBody>
      </CModal>
      </>
    )
  }
  
  
}

export default Login
```

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
useEffect(() => {
  getOrder();
  func()
  }, []);

const func = () =>{
if (order?.tableId === tableID) {
return (
  <>
  <h1>Text Example</h1>
  </>
)
} else {
 return (
  <>
  <h1>Text Example</h1>
  </>
 )
}
}
```

Maybe here the condition execute first before useEffect so you should put in the function and put function in useEffect.

Second write `if(order?.tableId === tableID)` condition that mean if there are order then check for tableId.

This solution is worked for me.

Comment: https://ibb.co/QvWn2dw I think dont work for me. It's like i dont have a return

Comment: https://ibb.co/2FMG4HV First is undefined and then 1

Answer (score 0):

With no reproduceable code, I'm gonna do alot of assumptions here.

1. the `getOrder` function is asynchroous call which updates state
2. the problem is really just order not being defined.

If these assumptions are correct, you may need to understand how [async operations work in javascript](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-the-event-loop-74cd408419ff).

Your best bet would be to check if order has been defined and double check if the order has a `tableId` prop like below

```js
if(order?.tableId !== undefined) {
    // perform your action here
}
```

Comment: This is good but dont work for me. I put all my code. If i do this i get an error like i dont have return.

Comment: I see what the issue is I created a dpaste of a  refactored  form of your code here: https://dpaste.com/BKBK9HCDP. Tots not the best approach its more of  a syntax issue( I presume)

Comment: This dont work. I copy the dpaste but dont work. Yeah i am think is syntax issue